# Combine WPCLI commands for plugin installation and activation?

Tags: wp-cli

Instead of running the command for plugin installation and then the command for activation:

```
sudo for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && wp plugin install elementor anywhere-elementor wordpress-seo wordfence contact-form-7; done
sudo for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && wp plugin activate elementor anywhere-elementor wordpress-seo wordfence contact-form-7; done
```

Can one combine both the install and activate to one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can one combine both the install and activate to one command?

It looks like you're looking for [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/install/) *plugin install* option

> [`--activate`]
>
> If set, the plugin will be activated immediately after
>   install.